# Self added script to Google goes away after I search something

Tags: javascript, google-search

I added a script to the google page. But when I search something it is away.
Here is my script:

```
function init(){
$("a").hover(
    function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var isURL = IsURL(href);

        if(isURL)alert("OK --- "+href);
        else alert("NO -----"+href);
    },
    function(){
        alert("OUT");
    }
);}
init();
```

How can I prevent Google removing my script?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "added a script to the google page" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you load a new page then changes you made to the previous page will be lost. You'll have to add the script to each new page when you load it.